# Move pod file outside of project directory

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

Can I move the Cocoapods' Podfile outside of the (git) project directory? I need to commit it as part of an umbrella project that includes an Xcode git submodule. (The Xcode project must still be able to find the Podfile.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I move the Cocoapods' Podfile outside of the (git) project
>   directory?

Absolutely! You just need to put your **Podfile** file in a directory you want and then edit the file targeting the **.xcodeproj** file of your Xcode project. Like so:

```
project 'ProjectName/ProjectName.xcodeproj'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'

platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
....
```

I hope this helps!